# Password-Protect file attributes

Tags: windows, encryption

Problem: We have internal environments with several configuration files, accessed by numerous people. We must ensure specific peoples are able to access the file for EDITING while being able to view the file content properly. I know there would be a way to do it with security, but it would require us to go through thousands of configuration files to set the security to specific members / groups. Also, we would like to be able to implement this new way of protecting the configurations files in our clients' servers (for our services).

Is there a way we can "password-Protect" the "Read-Only" attribute on Text files? (Someconfig.config).

[image: Read-only property]

Remember: the service will still use the configuration file, so the extension must not change, nor the content.

Comment: This don't seems to be asking about recommending software.

Comment: If you know a software that would do this, i'm down :)

Comment: BTW, the read-only attribute is obsolete, use security access permissions instead.

Comment: You may read in the upper section: I know there would be a way to do it with security, but it would require us to go through thousands of configuration files to set the security to specific members / groups.

Comment: Welcome. If you want to do it with just Windows, then ask on https://superuser.com/ - but the answer involves doing what you don't want to do. If you want an application to do it, then edit the question to ask for one. Your question is ***currently*** off-topic, but could be rephrased to make it on-topic.